# how to add separator automatically in DayPickerInput component of react-day-picker

Tags: react-day-picker

how can i add the `/ -` separator in DayPickerInput during the user digit?

for example in it locale: `23091989` digit should be equal to `23/09/1989`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass any formatter / parser to the `formatDate` or `parseDate` props:

http://react-day-picker.js.org/api/DayPickerInput#formatDate